# Can I use the home computer as the website server for offering the website?

Tags: networking, ipv6

My thinking is, the IPv6 resources are great many. can I use my home PC as a server, then config the IPv6 address on it. and bind the domain to the IPv6.

then I can provide my website to the public.

Because the website is not need keep running all the years and no network bandwidth need, we can ignore the servicing time requirement and bandwidth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes – any computer, with any kind of IP address, can act as a server.

Make sure the ISP allows this (some home ISPs deliberately block web serving), and that your IPv6 prefix is static. (Just as with dynamic IPv4, some ISPs like to change the IPv6 prefixes provided to customers.)

Although IPv6 does not need port forwarding, usually you'll still need to configure your router to *allow* the incoming connections in its firewall settings.

Note however that a large part of the Internet users still lack IPv6 access, so your web server will generally need both – IPv6 with its own address, and IPv4 with "traditional" port-forwarding. It's possible to get around this problem by pointing your domain at a reverse-proxy service (such as CloudFlare) instead of directly.

Comment: How to understand `a large part of the Internet users still lack IPv6 access`? can  you explain it? does the ipv4 can not access the ipv6 directly?

Comment: @three-blocks - No; It cannot

Comment: so the clients if under the ISP's NAT net, does it provide the ipv6 transition?

Comment: @three-blocks: No, IPv4-only clients usually remain IPv4-only until the ISP decides to roll out IPv6. Trying to implement NAT46 is problematic. However, the opposite (having v6-only users, but giving them v4 access through NAT64) is a bit more common.